# Map Identify tool in ArcGIS Server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, .net, arcgis-web-adf

I tried this http://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/map-identify-tool-in-arcgis-server/ but it doesn't work on ArcGIS Server 10.1 (.NET Web ADF) :-(
Application doesn’t use file MapIdentify.js. How to force the application to use this file and not default method from WebControls?